# calling an expect script from perl script

Tags: perl, expect

here is my perl script(a.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
$logfile = "./a.log";
open(LOGFILE_Handle, ">$logfile")  or die "Error : Can not open $logfile !!! \n\n ";
print LOGFILE_Handle "a.pl:  1 "; 
system "./a.exp ";
```

here is my expect script(a.exp)

```
#!/opt/sfw/bin/expect -f
log_user 1;
set logfile "./a.log";
set LOGFILE_Handle [open "$logfile" "a" 0666]
puts $LOGFILE_Handle "a.exp: A" 
send_user "Hi";
```

while running, the perl script, it doesnt call expect script..
is there anything im missing

Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you considered using Perl Expect module instead? http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you replace `system "./a.exp ";` with `system qw(expect ./a.exp);`

Alternatively, you should check that your execution directory allow you to refer to ./a.exp.